# javascript: get month/year/day/hours/minute timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

How to get year, month, day, hours, minute in  milliseconds of the selected date and time  in JavasScript?

```
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDay();
var year = date.getYear();
var hour= date.getHours();
var min= date.getMinutes();
```

All i want is *timestamp...*

Comment: All in milliseconds ?

Comment: the combination of this  in milliseconds and  date is already given and with current time i have to create the timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to get the timestamp in milliseconds is `getTime()` function.

```js
date = new Date();
console.log(date.getTime());
```

To get the timestamp for a particular date, pass the date and time in the format
`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` to the Date constructor

```js
date = new Date("03/27/2017 12:00");
console.log(date.getTime());
```

Comment: but date is already given and with current time i have to create the timestamp?

Comment: pass the date as new Date(date);

Comment: like this new Date(1/2/2017 12:00)? i really dont know please help

Comment: Answer updated. Check now. You can consider marking it as answer if it helped you @YogeshwarNair

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
date.getTime()
```